# Wordpress Custom Permalinks for a Category whose Posts are automatically generated

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I recently added a functionality to allow Twitter to create blog posts automatically whenever a new tweet is posted. As I'm using Wordpress Jetpack Publicize so I wanted the title of the posts to be the full tweet, that way it'll automatically update all my social channels.

As the `permalink` setting I'm using `%postname%` for all posts but in case of Twitter posts it gets way too long and creates issues with Backup and other things.

The Twitter post is assigned to a category `Tweets` so I want wordpress to set custom permalink for the same category posts. How can I do that?

You can see the twitter posts at my blog - http://robo.im/blog

`I'm using Wordpress Plugin Twitter Tools to fetch the new Tweets`

Answer (score 0):

Just set the custom premalinks to  `/%category%/` 
[here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) you can read what to do if posts have multiple categories.

But if not change urls for all categories, use custom post type instead of category, and follow one of many [tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20161114085835/http://firecask.com/custom-fields-and-posts-in-wordpress-permalink-urls/) how to change permalinks for that type.

Comment: It changes the permalinks of other posts as well, I want a solution wherein the permalink is changed only for the tweet category.